# How to return specific setting from DBCC USEROPTIONS?

Tags: sql-server

I need the date format, how do I select this specific data using sql?

SQL command:
`DBCC USEROPTIONS`

[image: **strong text**]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess

```
Declare @T table (Options varchar(100),Value varchar(100))
Insert Into @T 
Exec('DBCC USEROPTIONS')

Select * 
 From @T 
 Where Options ='dateformat'
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at sys.dm_exec_sessions system view. It contains the columns for the connection properties.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id=@@SPID;
```